# Apache 2.4 log PHP command 200 success, but what is it doing? POST /?q=die('z!a'.'x'); etc

Tags: apache-2.4, hacking, php7

I am running a CentOS 7.x VPS with Apache 2.4.29 and PHP 7.0.28 and I started seeing the following in my logs.  I have php.ini secured as best as I can from articles online for a while now, but I am wondering why I am seeing an HTTP status code of 200 success when they do the following and wondering what is it doing and how to prevent it?  As best as I can tell `die()` is the equivalent of `exit()`.  Is this a known older buffer overflow exploit?

Bottom line though is why is it returning success and what damage did it do?

```
[18/Mar/2018:09:57:21 +0000] "POST /?q=die('z!a'.'x');&w=die('z!a'.'x');&e=die('z!a'.'x');&r=die('z!a'.'x');&t=die('z!a'.'x');&y=die('z!a'.'x');&u=die('z!a'.'x');&i=die('z!a'.'x');&o=die('z!a'.'x');&p=die('z!a'.'x');&a=die('z!a'.'x');&s=die('z!a'.'x');&d=die('z!a'.'x');&f=die('z!a'.'x');&g=die('z!a'.'x');&h=die('z!a'.'x');&j=die('z!a'.'x');&k=die('z!a'.'x');&l=die('z!a'.'x');&z=die('z!a'.'x');&x=die('z!a'.'x');&c=die('z!a'.'x');&v=die('z!a'.'x');&b=die('z!a'.'x');&n=die('z!a'.'x');&m=die('z!a'.'x');&eval=die('z!a'.'x');&enter=die('z!a'.'x'); HTTP/1.1" 200 3564
```

Comment: I also got this in my log on the 17th

Comment: since none of the arguments were processed by my index page, it just shows the index, my guess it it targets a specific type of application

Comment: I made a modsec rule to block: SecRule ARGS "@contains ('z!a'.'x')" "id:9999,phase:2,t:none,t:lowercase,deny,status:403,log,msg:'UNKNOWN query attack'"

Comment: I've started seeing a whole bunch of these across many of my websites over the last two days (starting March 16). I'm glad to know it's not just me.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [What's so special about `eval(“z!ax”)`?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/181772/whats-so-special-about-evalzax)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a blind probe for PHP web application vulnerabilities. If you have a PHP web application which somehow executes code from untrusted input, from any of the query parameters given, then the script will die and print `z!ax` in the web page output.

If this happens, then the prober will come back later (maybe seconds later) to exploit the vulnerability for real.

Comment: My favorite response to these:

foreach (array_values($_POST) as $v) {
 if (preg_match("/die\(/", $v)) {
  print "go die() in a fire.";
  block($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
  die();
 }
};
foreach (array_values($_GET) as $v) {
 if (preg_match("/die\(/", $v)) {
  print "go die() in a fire.";
  block($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
  die();
 }
};